# HTTPS request with large json response fails to download [Tomcat]

Tags: google-chrome, https, tomcat7

I have a spring boot web app deployed on Tomcat 7.0.75 that we recently secured with https, having the following server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443"
  protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="50"
  server="web"
  allowTrace="false"
  keystoreFile="/app/certs/keystore.jks"
  keystorePass="wouldntYouLikeToKnow"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true"
  clientAuth="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
  ciphers="TLS_...SHA"
  maxSwallowSize="-1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="100"
  socket.soKeepAlive="true"/>`
```

When we went to https, requests having large (multiple MB) json response bodies started yielding an odd warning message in Chrome after reporting a 200 OK response code.  IE also fails to download the response fully.

[image]

It just keeps showing that warning forever and never completes the download.  Small requests work fine.  From a client perspective, the request has not yet completed, since neither the success function nor the error function for the https call executes.  As shown, the time to first byte (TTFB) is relatively fast, but a large amount of the time is spent during download and it never leaves that phase.  Tomcat evidently has kept the http connection open and the client is still expecting data, because when I close the browser, Tomcat reports a socket closed error.  Does anyone have an idea of what is going on and why the large response download never completes over https, but works fine over http?

**Edit 1**
Here is the curl command and response invoked from Linux.

```
curl -X GET   https://host.com/context   -H 'accept: application/json, 
text/plain, */*'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -H 'token: 12acdee7-ef76-
4147-98d2-d90e4414d4e6'   -H 'user-name: vn62253'   -H 'user-security-id: 1' 
-k -I

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-disposition, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-
Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, User-
Security-Id, Token, User-Name, Client-TZ-Offset
X-Application-Context: Compliance_WS:8765
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 14:33:47 GMT
Server: web
```

Comment: Do you use a load-balancer in front ? do you use native connector ? What happen if you use curl  ? Is there a content-length header in the response ? is there a gzip/deflate compression ?  if you check the response, is it send fully but block at the end ?

Comment: Yes, we use a load balancer.  We only use Tomcat's configurable http connector, as shown in the config.  If I use curl, it shows a bunch of json in the response, then just stops at specific point in the json.  The curl command never terminates.  I unfortunately cannot see the response in Chrome.  It is just a blank tab.  IE shows a large chunk, but not all of the expected response.  No content length header on the response.  I have tried with/without gzip, and it doesn't make a difference.  The response is just partial JSON, and it terminates in the middle of a JSON entry.

Comment: With curl can you check the content-size header ? and check the content that is really sent (does it stop at exactly content size ? ).   Is it possible that you have a content-size header but mode seems to be chunked ? What is the load balancer in front ? is it like  browser -> https -> load balancer (in https mode) ->  https -> tomcat (connector https) [ in this mode, your load balancer listen https, transform it, then call in a new ssl connexion your tomcat]? IS it possible to make a curl query directly to tomcat and compare with curl to load balancer ?

Comment: @wargre I included the curl command to lb server in my latest edit.  There is no content size header on the response.  None of my JSON reponses include a content-size header in either http or https.  The JSON response download does seem to stop at the exact same place every time.  I believe you have accurately described the https flow.  I can't actually curl to Tomcat directly, but only through lb server.

Comment: So it is a chuncked response. content-length not there, so it is not an incompatibility between the 2 mode. Long time ago I got an issue like that with chunked stream because of my load blancer. Check if there is no bug there. you can also try to do a https-> LB -> tomcat in http, and the oposite : http -> LB -> tomcat in https perhaps you will have one issue somewhere.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding    

chunked
    Data is sent in a series of chunks. The Content-Length header is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'. The terminating chunk is a regular chunk, with the exception that its length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of a (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.

Comment: It may happens if somewhere between client and tomcat you have problem with [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit). Why HTTP works? Maybe there is some difference in network routes between HTTP & HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the default timeout period of tomcat. If you can using load balancer like ngnix you can face this issue as it has default timeout interval of 1 minute.